# Getting a distinct aggregation of an array field across indexes

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to learn MongoDB and how it'd be useful for analytics for me. I'm simply playing around with the JavaScript console available on their website and have created the following items:

```
{"title": "Cool", "_id": {"$oid": "503e4dc0cc93742e0d0ccad3"}, "tags": ["twenty", "sixty"]}
{"title": "Other", "_id": {"$oid": "503e4e5bcc93742e0d0ccad4"}, "tags": ["ten", "thirty"]}
{"title": "Ouch", "_id": {"$oid": "503e4e72cc93742e0d0ccad5"}, "tags": ["twenty", "seventy"]}
{"title": "Final", "_id": {"$oid": "503e4e72cc93742e0d0ccad6"}, "tags": ["sixty", "seventy"]}
```

What I'd like to do is query so I get a list of unique tags for all of these objects. The result should look something like this:

```
["ten", "twenty", "thirty", "sixty", "seventy"]
```

How do I query for this? I'm trying to `distinct()` it, but the call always fails without even querying.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The code that fails on their website works on an actual MongoDB instance:

```
> db.posts.insert({title: "Hello", tags: ["one", "five"]});
> db.posts.insert({title: "World", tags: ["one", "three"]});
> db.posts.distinct("tags");
[ "one", "three", "five"]
```

Weird.

Comment: What error message do you get? I believe the console is running on a very old mongo version...

Answer (score 16):

You can use the aggregation framework.  Depending on how you'd like the results structured, you can use either

```
var pipeline = [ 
        {"$unwind": "$tags" } ,
        { "$group": { _id: "$tags" } }
    ];
R = db.tb.aggregate( pipeline );
printjson(R);

{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "seventy"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "ten"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "sixty"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "thirty"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "twenty"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

or

```
var pipeline = [ 
        {"$unwind": "$tags" } ,
        { "$group": 
            { _id: null, tags: {"$addToSet": "$tags" }  }
        }
    ];
R = db.tb.aggregate( pipeline );
printjson(R);

{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : null,
                        "tags" : [
                                "seventy",
                                "ten",
                                "sixty",
                                "thirty",
                                "twenty"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is really helpful. What if we want to write the tags into another collections ?

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to use this:

```
db.mycollection.distinct("tags").sort()
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way of getting unique array elements using aggregation pipeline

```
db.blogs.aggregate(
  [
    {$group:{_id : null, uniqueTags : {$push : "$tags"}}},
    {$project:{
      _id : 0,
      uniqueTags : {
        $reduce : {
          input : "$uniqueTags", 
          initialValue :[], 
          in : {$let : {
            vars : {elem : { $concatArrays : ["$$this", "$$value"] }},
            in : {$setUnion : "$$elem"}
          }}
        }
      }
    }}
  ]
)
```

collection

```
> db.blogs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d53faca11d88f428a2999"), "name" : "sdfdef", "tags" : [ "abc", "def", "efg", "abc" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d5434ca11d88f428a299a"), "name" : "abcdef", "tags" : [ "abc", "ijk", "lmo", "zyx" ] }
>
```

pipeline

```
>   db.blogs.aggregate(
...     [
...       {$group:{_id : null, uniqueTags : {$push : "$tags"}}},
...       {$project:{
...         _id : 0,
...         uniqueTags : {
...           $reduce : {
...             input : "$uniqueTags", 
...             initialValue :[], 
...             in : {$let : {
...               vars : {elem : { $concatArrays : ["$$this", "$$value"] }},
...               in : {$setUnion : "$$elem"}
...             }}
...           }
...         }
...       }}
...     ]
...   )
```

result

```
{ "uniqueTags" : [ "abc", "def", "efg", "ijk", "lmo", "zyx" ] }
```

Comment: You can use $addToSet instead of $push in the $group step. This will automatically create a unique set of array: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: @whati001 here, `$push` is pushing arrays into an array, so `$addToSet` would not have the effect you're describing -- right? Unless you use the [`$each` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#mongodb-update-up.-each), but I'm not sure that's available for aggregation/group stages, only update operations

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of web mongo consoles available:

- http://try.mongodb.org/
- http://www.mongodb.org/#

But if you type help in them you will realise they only support a very small number of ops:

```
HELP
Note: Only a subset of MongoDB's features are provided here.
For everything else, download and install at mongodb.org.

db.foo.help()                 help on collection method
db.foo.find()                 list objects in collection foo
db.foo.save({a: 1})           save a document to collection foo
db.foo.update({a: 1}, {a: 2}) update document where a == 1
db.foo.find({a: 1})           list objects in foo where a == 1

it                            use to further iterate over a cursor
```

As such distinct does not work because it is not supported.

Comment: @wkhatch if you read the question again the OP was asking how to do aggregation in the web console that used to provided on the MongoDB site. I correctly answered that you cannot