# List all values of a certain field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

How would I get an array containing all values of a certain field for all of my documents in a collection?

db.collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be6"), "x" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be7"), "x" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be8"), "x" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be9"), "x" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990bea"), "x" : 5 }
```

"db.collection.ListAllValuesForfield(x)"
Result: [1,2,3,4,5]

Also, what if this field was an array?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be6"), "y" : [1,2] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be7"), "y" : [3,4] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be8"), "y" : [5,6] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990be9"), "y" : [1,2] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a7dc7b2cacf40b79990bea"), "y" : [3,4] }
```

"db.collection.ListAllValuesInArrayField(y)"
Result: [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]

Additionally, can I make this array unique? [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a distinct aggregation of an array field across indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183444/getting-a-distinct-aggregation-of-an-array-field-across-indexes)

Comment: Perfect thank you! Should I take this down?

Comment: The mongo shell extension for db.distinctAndCount is very nice. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30215651/1276299

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`db.collection.distinct('x')`

should give you an array of unique values for that field.

Comment: This is just what I needed! What's interesting to note is that there is an additional parameter (the second one) that specifies a document query `db.collection.distinct('users.id', {  document: { $in: [...]  } }`

Comment: The syntax for nested documents: `db.collection.distinct('x.nestedField')`

Comment: The always useful "distinct and count" aggregations / mongo shell extension for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924495/mongodb-count-num-of-distinct-values-per-field-key/14928718

Comment: I was looking for 'group by' just like in sql to get this list, distinct() worked very well and so simple!

Answer (score 10):

**Notice:** My answer is a fork from the original answer.

Before any "thumbs up" here, "thumbs up" the accepted answer :).

---

`db.collection.distinct("NameOfTheField")`

> Finds the distinct values for a specified field across a single collection or view and returns the results in an array.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment on the original answer.

Answer (score 8):

This would return an array of docs, containing just it's x value...

```
db.collection.find(
    { },
    { x: 1, y: 0, _id:0 }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @lascort: This `find` not return "an array", but a cursor... To get an distinct array of `x` values with *this method,* you can do:
`A = new Array();
db.collection.find().forEach( D => A.push(D.x) );
U = [... new Set(A)]`

Answer (score 2):

`db.collection_name.distinct("key/field_name")`    - This will return a list of distinct values in the key name from the entire dictionary.

Just make sure you don't use the curly brackets after round brackets.