# mongodb. how to select distinct records

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I need to get documents only with distinct values

SQL should be something like this: `SELECT DISTINCT engine_type_id FROM cars`
But I have no idea how to get same behaviour in the mongo.

Thank in advance.

P.S. I tried to use mongo's `distinct` method, but it returns array of distinct engine_type_id instead of whole documents. So it's doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Look at this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183444/getting-a-distinct-aggregation-of-an-array-field-across-indexes) that returns distinct values for any filed containing single or multiple values. hence as per your need you have to writer some [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Read more about [mongodb distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) functionality.

Comment: Which documents have the given value of `engine_type_id` do you want with a distinct value of `engine_type_id`? One per distinct value (which one?), all of them? Technically, just retrieving all documents in the collection is finding the distinct values of `engine_type_id` along with all documents having those values, so you need to be more specific about what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `distinct` method with **2** arguments.

Here is how I get all ids:
`ids = db.cars .distinct("_id", "engine_type_id")`

Next I can hit db with next query:
`db.cars.find({"_id": {$in: ids}})`

So, that's all!

For those, who using ruby with MongoMapper, please take a look here:

```
ids = MongoMapper.database.eval("db.cars.distinct('_id', 'engine_type_id'})")
Car.where(_id: { :$in => ids })
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with mongomapper, but the same synax works with mongoid.

Here is an answer that works for me:

```
ap WaterSupply.distinct(:thread_type)
[
    [0] "NST",
    [1] "5\" NST",
    [2] "",
    [3] "JSN"
]
```

You can also chain it with scopes/where clauses:

```
org.users.active.distinct(:role_ids)
```