# How to get a concatenated list of an attirbute of a documents array property?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this structure:

```
db.mycollection.find({_id: 1})
{
  _id: 1,
  attribute: [
    {
      sub_id: abc,
    },
    {
      sub_id: djxk,
    }
  ]
}
```

What I now want is a concatenated string comma separated with all sub_ids over all documents of the collection. `{sub_id: "abc, djxk"}`

What I've tried:

```
db.mycollection.mapReduce( function() { emit("mycollections", this._id); }, function(key, values) { return values.join(", ")}, {out: "sub_ids"})
```

But the result is not as expected:

```
{
    "result" : "sub_ids",
    "timeMillis" : 652,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3837,
            "emit" : 3837,
            "reduce" : 40,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What is the right function and parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Mongo's map-reduce will store the final output in a collection (in this case in the `sub_id` collection). Have you thought about using an aggregation pipeline instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a distinct aggregation of an array field across indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183444/getting-a-distinct-aggregation-of-an-array-field-across-indexes)

Comment: `db.mycollection.distinct('attribute.sub_id')`

Comment: How would this pipeline look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "sub_id": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$attribute",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": { "$concat": ["$$this.sub_id", ",", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8mhFcpvcV3n)